# What is wrong with this proof of the derivative product rule?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, solution-verification

I was trying to prove the derivative product rule, but I got a wrong result and nothing seems wrong with my proof. If someone could help me, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks  in advance
$f(x) = g(x)h(x)$
Prove $f^\prime (x) = g(x)^\prime h(x) + g(x)h(x)^\prime$
My proof:
\begin{align}
f^\prime (x)
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)h(x+h) - g(x)h(x)}{h}\\ 
&=\lim_{h \to 0} \left(\frac{g(x+h)}{h} \cdot h(x+h)\right)-\lim_{h \to 0} \left(\frac{g(x)}{h} \cdot h(x) \right)\\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)}{h} \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} h(x+h) - \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{h} \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} h(x)\\
&= h(x) \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)}{h} - h(x) \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{h} \\
&= h(x) \left( \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)}{h} - \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{h} \right)\\
&= h(x) \cdot \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}{h} \\
&= h(x) \cdot g^\prime (x)
\end{align}

Comment: Don't use $h$ for both the limit parameter and the second function. (It's evident from context, but there's no reason to overload $h$.)

Comment: You can't split apart a limit of a difference when you don't already know if the two parts actually have a limit: $\lim_{h \to 0} (1/h - 1/h) = 0$ but that is not $\lim_{h \to 0} 1/h - \lim_{h \to 0} 1h$.  This is the kind of error you are making.

Comment: A suggestion, start with the result and work backwards.

Comment: Likewise, you cannot split $\lim(\frac{g(x+h)}{h}f(x+h))$ into the product of the limits (line 4, after renaming the second function to avoid the double use of $h$) unless you already know that $\lim\frac{g(x+h)}{h}$ exists ($f$ is presumably continuous, so the other limit does exist). The limit laws require you to assume all limits on the right hand side exist, and you do not know that here, twice.

Comment: Following up on @KCd 's comment, here's an exercise for you: Identify which of the quantities in your derivation are most likely infinite. If you want to make it more concrete, use the functions $x^2$ and $x^3$, and look at $x=1$.

Comment: In the 3rd line the two limits do not exist unless $g(x)h(x)=0.$ In the 4th line the limits $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x+h)}{h}$ and $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{g(x)}{h}$ do not exist unless $g(x)=0.$ Of course if $g(x)$ is $0$ then $f'(x)=g(x)h'(x)+h(x)g'(x)=0\cdot h'(x)+h(x)g'(x)=h(x)g'(x).$ BTW you can use the apostrophe f' instead of  f ^{\prime}.

Answer (score 1):

In the derivative, $f(x+h)-f(x)$ tends to $0$, so the limit $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ as $h\to0$ is defined. $f(x+h)$ does not generally tend to $0$, so the limit $\frac{f(x+h)}{h}$ as $h\to0$ is not defined.